# Remove event context canvas render when finished

Tags: html5-canvas, openlayers, angular-openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to compare two Vector Layers.
One Layer is the main layer and gets loaded with the map the other layer get's loaded
after when I want to compare the 2 layers.
(Desired behavior) When I am done comparing I want to go back to the initial state of the map but (Problem) I can't seem to get rid of the canvas "slices" that were created when comparing.

I've created a demo of the code here (Code Sample)

https://codesandbox.io/s/layer-swipe-compare-uceihq?file=/main.js

minus the removing the "slices" and going back to the original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unset the `prerender` and `postrender` listeners and remove the layer that you added (which should be created only once).

https://codesandbox.io/s/layer-swipe-compare-forked-muihye?file=/main.js